# How can I solve the Syntax Error in MariaDB when I use DataStudio

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, looker-studio

I'm doing a personalized query in Data Studio, which was originally made in MySQL, but I have been having the next error when a I use one of the fields of the result.

Error with SQL statement:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>= '20200301' AND  <= '20200331')' at line 34

This is the query and the file with the error is pm.meta_value which is related with the pm.meta_key:

```
SELECT
p.ID as código,
p.post_title,
pm.meta_value,
entidad.name,
CASE WHEN tv.URL != ''
            THEN 'SI'
            ELSE 'NO'
END,
t.name,
tv.URL,
p.post_date
FROM wp_posts p
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships rs ON p.ID=rs.object_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON rs.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN wp_terms AS t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
  LEFT JOIN  (select p.ID, pm.meta_value as URL FROM wp_posts p
            LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
            where pm.meta_key in ('test')
            and pm.meta_value != ''
            ) as tv on p.ID = tv.ID
  INNER JOIN (select p.ID, t.name name, tt.taxonomy taxonomy FROM wp_posts p
              LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships rs ON p.ID=rs.object_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON rs.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
              INNER JOIN wp_terms AS t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
            ) as entidad on p.ID = entidad.ID
WHERE p.post_type ='test1'
  AND p.post_status =  'test2'
  AND pm.meta_key = 'test3'
  AND entidad.taxonomy = 'test4'
  AND (tt.term_id = 15 OR
       tt.term_id = 174 OR 
       tt.term_id = 1960);
```

Comment: Where is line 34?   Your error message doesn't appear in the query code you've posted

Comment: there must be some other queries I guess

Comment: Must be `... (tablename.fieldname >= '20200301' AND tablename.fieldname <= '20200331')`.

Comment: @Sparky Line 34 is the last line in the query, beacuse every OR is in a line. Althaugh, if I have the ORs in the same line, the error is in line 32.

Comment: @Akina In the query I don't have that statement

Comment: MariaDB shows a fragment of problematic query in the error message. Precisely - `'>= '20200301' AND <= '20200331')'`. But this fragment is absent in a query which you show - so you have problem NOT in shown query. So first figure out what and where the problem is...

Comment: Hello guys, I'm so sorry with you, it was a mistake when I called a variable, because a i was using "código" and the accent mark in letter o is not accepted in MariaDB or data studio. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was when I named the variable p.ID as "código", because MariaDB or DataStudio doesn't accept the accent mark in the letter o.